# R read_fwf Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) for very large files

Tags: r, readr

I am able to read files which are about 200MB+, but when I try to read a very large file (2GB) using read_fwf I always get the error message below.

```
res <- read_fwf(file=file,
              fwf_positions(c(1,5,10,20,30,35,45,95,205,225,235,245,255,
                              325,545,555,565,575,585,595,605,615,836),
                            c(4,9,19,24,34,44,54,104,214,234,244,254,264,
                              334,554,564,574,584,594,604,614,624,836),col_names=w),
              skip=9, 
              n_max = Inf,
              progress = interactive()
              )
```

Error Msg:

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : Cannot read file E:/.. output.hru 
Called from: guess_types_(datasource, tokenizer, locale, n = n)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe try `guess_max=100` since it seems to be getting stuck at the guessing phase. Of if you know the data types, might be better just to specify them rather than relying on guessing. Hard to say without a reproducible example.

Comment: I tried  guess_max=100 but I get this error unused argument (guess_max = 100).

Comment: What version of `readr` are you using? The documentation for `readr_1.1.1` says it exists.

Comment: It looks like I was using readr_0.2.2. I'll update it, maybe this was the problem.

Comment: It works now :) thanks @MrFlick